# What is the difference between [[String:String]]! and [[String:String]]() in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I am working on a project where I found an array variable

```
var items: [[String: String]]!
```

I searched in google how to define an empty array, I got the result as

```
var itemsNew: [[String: String]]()
```

while using items array getting an error while appending data

```
 self.appDelegate.items.append([Name: "sdsd",
                                 rate: "0.2",
                                 Quantity:"3",
                                 Taxable:"true",
                                  Category: "",
                                 inven: "true",
                                  amount : "0.23",
                                 mod: "",
                                 darray: "",
                                 list: "",
                                 famount: "0.0"])
```

giving an error "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file". I am giving hardcore value but still, it's crashing. Don't know why it's crashing. can somebody help me?

Comment: do you tried: var items = [[String: String]]()

Comment: No actually var items = [[String: String]]! this variable is written by the previous developer, and it's working for previous code, so don't want to change, maybe it shows some error, that's why not changed

Comment: ! means that it is optional (same as ?) but that it can be expected that the variable is always initialised anyway

Comment: If you don't want to change the declaration of `items` then you need to search the code so you find the place where it is being initialised because before this happens you can not use that property. Personally I would recommend to change the declaration though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[String: String]]()` is an object of Array of type `[[String: String]]`.

Where as `[[String: String]]!` is an arrayType of type `[[String: String]]` which can't be nil while executing because it is an implicitly unwrapped optional.

You are getting `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file` because `items` was never initialised. But you are trying to add an item to `items` which is actually a null value. You can solve this error by replacing `items` declaration with the below code.

```
var items: [[String: String]] = [[String: String]]()
```

And the declaration of itemsNew is also wrong. You can declare it as below.

```
var itemsNew = [[String: String]]()
```

or

```
var itemsNew: [[String: String]] = [[String: String]]()
```

Comment: Thanks, Rupesh, I didn't understand the initialization and types of difference

Comment: The second thing is also an array of `[String:String]` (an array of dictionaries) but it is implicitly unwrapped as you explained.

Comment: @user3120670. I updated the answer. You can't use an object unless you initialise it as it don't have an allocated memory. When you are declaring an object as `[[String: String]]!`, you are declaring it but not initialising it, due to which the app is crashing as the object don't have memory.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
var items: [[String: String]]! not allocating memory or giving back, the reference to item where developer can append the items.
```

So `var itemsNew: [[String: String]]()`is working as it is creating memory where you can append items.

Answer (score 1):

The first object `items` is declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional. If you use it as `items` without the `?` optionally unwrapping, you're saying that you know for sure that there is a value in `items` I'm sure it's not `nil` if it doesn't have a value I want the app to crash.

In the second case, you're creating a `non-optional` empty array of dictionary `itemsNew` which cannot be `nil` but is empty at the time of declaration. In summary, you can replace the optional declaration to empty declaration they would still store the same type in these properties.

```
var items = [[String: String]]()
var itemsNew = [[String: String]]()
```